# How to use linq's .Include() when using EF 4.1 on an inverse property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I am having trouble figuring out how to use `.Include()` to be able to access this nested relationship. I tried what seemed like the most direct way but intellisense doesn't populate and when I hand enter the relation there is a compilation error.

I have this db mapped setup

```
public class W
{
 public int WId { get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection<T> Ts { get; set; }
}

public class T
{
 public int TId { get; set; }
 public int WId { get; set; }
 public int CId { get; set; }
 public virtual W W { get; set; }
 public virtual C { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
 public int CId { get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection<T> Ts { get; set; }
}
```

I have a get method which queries

```
//set in constructor
DbSet<W> dbSet;
DbContext context;

//called in method
IQueryable<W> query = dbSet;
query = query.Include(w => w.Ts);//works
query = query.Include(w => w.Ts.C); //I wanted to do this but it doesn't work
```

### Can I use `.Include()` like this?

It seemed like it was going to work with no hitch but apparently I am doing it wrong. I would prefer not to have to iterate through the Ts collection and then populate their C manually each time.

Comment: BTW: Didn't you mean "nested" property instead of "inverse" in your question title?

Comment: @Slauma - No, the virtual collection is considered an inverse property I thought. Class T holds the foreign key for W, and W holds a collection of T objects with that foreign key. I was under the impression this was considered an inverse property, and you can even explicitly label it with the data annotation which would apply here as `[InverseProperty("W")]` above W's definition for the Ts ICollection (although that would be redundant as EF will do this automatically if the Id's and foreign navigation names use the naming convention)

Comment: The `W.T` collection is an inverse property of the `T.W` reference and the `T.W` reference is an inverse property of the `W.T` collection, it's "symmetric" somehow. Your question looks more like `W -> T -> C`, `C` "is nested" in `T` :) The answer would also apply if you remove `T.W` and `C.Ts`, then there is nothing inverse anymore. Anyway, forget my comment, I just thought it was a typo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
query = query.Include(w => w.Ts.Select(t => t.C));
```

Comment: Using this syntax I came across an issue of loading the wrong data. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11676513/1026459