# How can I use Entity Framework on an object graph past a depth of 2 with MySQL Connector / NET?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework-4.1, eager-loading

Here is a confirmed bug report with Oracle: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67183

**Situation**

When using an `.Include` chain inside of my repository, I noticed that I was getting strange results - mostly that the values queried that were being returned were from the wrong fields (name would end up in description for example - but in the database all the values are correct, they only show up wrong after the query). I changed the names so the relationships are more obvious, but the structure is the same. I keep getting the wrong values for the associated CrewMember and their relative Rank and Clearance. It seems if there is a field name which is the same in CrewMember as Rank, then the value of that field in Rank becomes what the value was in CrewMember. For example, if Rank had a description, and so did CrewMember, then the description of Rank for the CrewMember would be the CrewMember's description.

Entity Framework fails to make well formed queries past a depth of 2 when there are similar fields defined as a result of the MySQL Connector/NET sql provider failing to properly form `join` statements.

**Definitions**

This is a class definition which models a database table. I am using C# ASP.NET MVC 3 with the Entity Framework 4.1 and the MySQL Connector/NET version 6.5

```
public class Harbor
{
 public int HarborId { get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection<Ship> Ships { get; set; }
 public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Ship
{
 public int ShipId { get; set; }
 public int HarborId { get; set; }
 public virtual Harbor Harbor { get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection<CrewMember> CrewMembers { get; set; }
 public string Description { get; set; }
} 

public class CrewMember
{
 public int CrewMemberId { get; set; }
 public int ShipId { get; set; }
 public virtual Ship Ship { get; set; }
 public int RankId { get; set; }
 public virtual Rank Rank { get; set; }
 public int ClearanceId { get; set; }
 public virtual Clearance Clearance { get; set; }
 public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Rank
{
 public int RankId { get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection<CrewMember> CrewMembers { get; set; }
 public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Clearance
{
 public int ClearanceId { get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection<CrewMember> CrewMembers { get; set; }
 public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**Query**

This is the code which queries the database and has the query and .Include calls.

```
DbSet<Harbor> dbSet = context.Set<Harbor>();
IQueryable<Harbor> query = dbSet;
query = query.Include(entity => entity.Ships);
query = query.Include(entity => entity.Ships.Select(s => s.CrewMembers));
query = query.Include(entity => entity.Ships.Select(s => s.CrewMembers.Select(cm => cm.Rank)));
query = query.Include(entity => entity.Ships.Select(s => s.CrewMembers.Select(cm => cm.Clearance)));
```

Are these `.Include` calls well formed? Did I miss something?

This is rather complex, so if you have any questions please let me know in comments and I will try to clarify anything I may have left out.

**How can I use Entity Framework to get a well formed query on an object graph past a depth of 2 when using MySQL Connector / NET?**

**Edits**

Here is the generated query:

```
{SELECT
[Project1].[HarborId], 
[Project1].[Description], 
[Project1].[C2] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[ShipId], 
[Project1].[HarborId1], 
[Project1].[Description1], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C2], 
[Project1].[CrewMemberId], 
[Project1].[ShipId1], 
[Project1].[ClearanceId], 
[Project1].[RankId], 
[Project1].[Description2], 
[Project1].[RankId1], 
[Project1].[Description3], 
[Project1].[ClearanceId1], 
[Project1].[Description4], 
FROM (SELECT
[Extent1].[HarborId], 
[Extent1].[Description], 
[Join3].[ShipId], 
[Join3].[HarborId] AS [HarborId1], 
[Join3].[Description]AS [Description1], 
[Join3].[CrewMemberId], 
[Join3].[ShipId]AS [ShipId1], 
[Join3].[ClearanceId], 
[Join3].[RankId], 
[Join3].[Description] AS [Description2], 
[Join3].[RankId] AS [RankId1], 
[Join3].[Description] AS [Description3], 
[Join3].[ClearanceId] AS [ClearanceId1], 
[Join3].[Description] AS [Description4], 
CASE WHEN ([Join3].[ShipId] IS  NULL) THEN (NULL)  WHEN ([Join3].[CrewMemberId] IS  NULL) THEN (NULL)  ELSE (1) END AS [C1], 
CASE WHEN ([Join3].[ShipId] IS  NULL) THEN (NULL)  ELSE (1) END AS [C2]
FROM [Harbor] AS [Extent1] LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
[Extent2].[ShipId], 
[Extent2].[HarborId], 
[Extent2].[Description], 
[Join2].[CrewMemberId], 
[Join2].[ShipId] AS [ShipID1], 
[Join2].[ClearanceId], 
[Join2].[RankId], 
[Join2].[Description] AS [DESCRIPTION1], 
[Join2].[RankID1], 
[Join2].[DESCRIPTION1] AS [DESCRIPTION11], 
[Join2].[ClearanceID1], 
[Join2].[DESCRIPTION2], 
FROM [Ship] AS [Extent2] LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
[Extent3].[CrewMemberId], 
[Extent3].[ShipId], 
[Extent3].[ClearanceId], 
[Extent3].[RankId], 
[Extent3].[Description], 
[Extent4].[RankId] AS [RankID1], 
[Extent4].[Description] AS [DESCRIPTION1], 
[Extent5].[ClearanceId] AS [ClearanceID1], 
[Extent5].[Description] AS [DESCRIPTION2], 
FROM [CrewMember] AS [Extent3] INNER JOIN [Rank] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[RankId] = [Extent4].[RankId] LEFT OUTER JOIN [Clearance] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent3].[ClearanceId] = [Extent5].[ClearanceId]) AS [Join2] ON [Extent2].[ShipId] = [Join2].[ShipId]) AS [Join3] ON [Extent1].[HarborId] = [Join3].[HarborId]
 WHERE [Extent1].[HarborId] = @p__linq__0) AS [Project1]
 ORDER BY 
[Project1].[HarborId] ASC, 
[Project1].[C2] ASC, 
[Project1].[ShipId] ASC, 
[Project1].[C1] ASC}
```

**Clarification**

Using include on 1-1 relationships poses no problem when "drilling down" in this fashion it seems. However, the issue seems to arise when there are 1-many relations as part of the drilling. The drilling is necessary in order to eager load.

The first projection, `entity => entity.Ships.Select(s => s.CrewMembers`, will return a list of CrewMembers which are related to each ship. This properly returns the graph where a harbor contains a list of ships, each with a list of crew members.

However, the second projection `CrewMembers.Select(cm => cm.Rank`, does not in fact return the proper piece of the graph. Fields begin to be mixed, and any fields sharing the same name will default for whatever reason to the parent field. This results in inconsistent results and more importantly bad data. The fact that no errors are thrown makes it worse, as this can only be determined through runtime inspection.

If there were a way to somehow get a strongly typed single response (as opposed to a list) from the first projection, perhaps the second would not be necessary. As it is now, I believe that the issue lies in the first projection returning a list. When the second projection attempts to project based on that list instead of from a single object, the logical error is introduced.

If, instead of CrewMembers being an ICollection, it was only one CrewMember, then this nested projection will in fact return the correct data. However, that is a simplified version of this problem and unfortunately it is what almost all testing seems to have been done on from the various blogs, tutorials, posts, articles, and documents which I reviewed trying to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you post a sample SQL statement sent to the db? Ultimately, that should determine which property values go where in the graph.

Comment: @danludwig - See edit for SQL statement.

Comment: Is the problem reproducable for you with the model you have posted? I would try to test it then. "*Mixing fields*" would be a pretty serious bug, I think, which should be reported in a reproducable way to the EF team.

Comment: @Slauma - Not only is it reproducible, but when using a second projection other logical errors occur as well such as over-eager loading (grabbing more than was requested). This issue is currently unresolved in their newest deployment, was untested in their design, and is even partially acknowledged by their team. I came across a post from their team (hard to find because I must have read literally dozens of pages) which said using projections can become unreliable. Include has been an issue from day 1 for them. First with "magic strings", then with "unofficial fixes" released by team members.

Comment: Don't have anything to add but I'd just like to say this is a very useful post for anyone into MVC3 and EF, well done to @Slauma and danludwig for their efforts and replies

Comment: @TravisJ: Oracle claims that the problem has been fixed in newer MySQL connector versions (see last reply in your bug report http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67183). Can you confirm it? Perhaps you can share your experience in this question which describes almost the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007589/entity-framework-returning-incorrect-data-from-columns-with-same-name

Comment: @Slauma - I did see the update although I have been unable to test that it is properly working. I managed to create several workarounds which are currently in place and have not had the time to go back and profile the newest version. Thanks for the heads up though, I will keep an update in mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit**

The test below was made with SQL Server and `SqlClient` as provider. The fact that the problem is not reproducable with SQL Server raises the question if the `MySql` provider you are using has a bug in that is creates incorrect SQL for your LINQ query. It looks like the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825643/why-doesnt-this-include-work) where the problem occured with a `MySql` provider as well and couldn't be reproduced with `SqlClient`/SQL Server.

---

> I keep getting the wrong values for the associated CrewMember and
>   their relative Rank and Clearance. It seems if there is a field name
>   which is the same in CrewMember as Rank, then the value of that field
>   in Rank becomes what the value was in CrewMember. **For example, if Rank
>   had a description, and so did CrewMember, then the description of Rank
>   for the CrewMember would be the CrewMember's description.**

I have tested the example in bold (with EF 4.3.1) and can't reproduce the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace EFInclude
{
    public class Harbor
    {
        public int HarborId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Ship> Ships { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class Ship
    {
        public int ShipId { get; set; }
        public int HarborId { get; set; }
        public virtual Harbor Harbor { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CrewMember> CrewMembers { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class CrewMember
    {
        public int CrewMemberId { get; set; }
        public int ShipId { get; set; }
        public virtual Ship Ship { get; set; }
        public int RankId { get; set; }
        public virtual Rank Rank { get; set; }
        public int ClearanceId { get; set; }
        public virtual Clearance Clearance { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rank
    {
        public int RankId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CrewMember> CrewMembers { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class Clearance
    {
        public int ClearanceId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CrewMember> CrewMembers { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Harbor> Harbors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ship> Ships { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CrewMember> CrewMembers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Rank> Ranks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Clearance> Clearances { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>());

            using (var context = new MyContext())
            {
                context.Database.Initialize(true);

                var harbor = new Harbor
                {
                    Ships = new HashSet<Ship>
                    {
                        new Ship
                        {
                            CrewMembers = new HashSet<CrewMember>
                            {
                                new CrewMember
                                {
                                    Rank = new Rank { Description = "Rank A" },
                                    Clearance = new Clearance { Description = "Clearance A" },
                                    Description = "CrewMember A"
                                },
                                new CrewMember
                                {
                                    Rank = new Rank { Description = "Rank B" },
                                    Clearance = new Clearance { Description = "Clearance B" },
                                    Description = "CrewMember B"
                                }
                            },
                            Description = "Ship AB"
                        },
                        new Ship
                        {
                            CrewMembers = new HashSet<CrewMember>
                            {
                                new CrewMember
                                {
                                    Rank = new Rank { Description = "Rank C" },
                                    Clearance = new Clearance { Description = "Clearance C" },
                                    Description = "CrewMember C"
                                },
                                new CrewMember
                                {
                                    Rank = new Rank { Description = "Rank D" },
                                    Clearance = new Clearance { Description = "Clearance D" },
                                    Description = "CrewMember D"
                                }
                            },
                            Description = "Ship CD"
                        }
                    },
                    Description = "Harbor ABCD"
                };

                context.Harbors.Add(harbor);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (var context = new MyContext())
            {
                DbSet<Harbor> dbSet = context.Set<Harbor>();
                IQueryable<Harbor> query = dbSet;
                query = query.Include(entity => entity.Ships);
                query = query.Include(entity => entity.Ships.Select(s => s.CrewMembers));
                query = query.Include(entity => entity.Ships.Select(s => s.CrewMembers.Select(cm => cm.Rank)));
                query = query.Include(entity => entity.Ships.Select(s => s.CrewMembers.Select(cm => cm.Clearance)));

                var sqlString = query.ToString();
                // see below for the generated SQL query

                var harbor = query.Single();

                Console.WriteLine("Harbor {0} Description = \"{1}\"",
                    harbor.HarborId, harbor.Description);
                foreach (var ship in harbor.Ships)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Ship {0} Description = \"{1}\"",
                        ship.ShipId, ship.Description);
                    foreach (var crewMember in ship.CrewMembers)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("-- CrewMember {0} Description = \"{1}\"", 
                            crewMember.CrewMemberId, crewMember.Description);
                        Console.WriteLine("-- CrewMember {0} Rank Description = \"{1}\"",
                            crewMember.CrewMemberId, crewMember.Rank.Description);
                        Console.WriteLine("-- CrewMember {0} Clearance Description = \"{1}\"",
                            crewMember.CrewMemberId, crewMember.Clearance.Description);
                    }
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

[image]

According to your description in bold I should have: **CrewMember 1 Description = "Rank A"** and the same mess for the other 3 crew members. But I haven't this.

Is something different in my test program compared to your code where you have the error?

**Edit**

The generated SQL for the query (see line `var sqlString = query.ToString();` in source code above, the following is the content of `sqlString`) is:

```sql
SELECT 
[Project1].[HarborId] AS [HarborId], 
[Project1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Project1].[C2] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[ShipId] AS [ShipId], 
[Project1].[HarborId1] AS [HarborId1], 
[Project1].[Description1] AS [Description1], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C2], 
[Project1].[CrewMemberId] AS [CrewMemberId], 
[Project1].[ShipId1] AS [ShipId1], 
[Project1].[RankId] AS [RankId], 
[Project1].[ClearanceId] AS [ClearanceId], 
[Project1].[Description2] AS [Description2], 
[Project1].[RankId1] AS [RankId1], 
[Project1].[Description3] AS [Description3], 
[Project1].[ClearanceId1] AS [ClearanceId1], 
[Project1].[Description4] AS [Description4]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[HarborId] AS [HarborId], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Join3].[ShipId1] AS [ShipId], 
    [Join3].[HarborId] AS [HarborId1], 
    [Join3].[Description1] AS [Description1], 
    [Join3].[CrewMemberId] AS [CrewMemberId], 
    [Join3].[ShipId2] AS [ShipId1], 
    [Join3].[RankId1] AS [RankId], 
    [Join3].[ClearanceId1] AS [ClearanceId], 
    [Join3].[Description2] AS [Description2], 
    [Join3].[RankId2] AS [RankId1], 
    [Join3].[Description3] AS [Description3], 
    [Join3].[ClearanceId2] AS [ClearanceId1], 
    [Join3].[Description4] AS [Description4], 
    CASE WHEN ([Join3].[ShipId1] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Join3].[CrewMemberId] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
    CASE WHEN ([Join3].[ShipId1] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C2]
    FROM  [dbo].[Harbors] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[ShipId] AS [ShipId1], [Extent2].[HarborId] AS [HarborId], [Extent2].[Description] AS [Description1], [Join2].[CrewMemberId], [Join2].[ShipId2], [Join2].[RankId1], [Join2].[ClearanceId1], [Join2].[Description2], [Join2].[RankId2], [Join2].[Description3], [Join2].[ClearanceId2], [Join2].[Description4]
        FROM  [dbo].[Ships] AS [Extent2]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent3].[CrewMemberId] AS [CrewMemberId], [Extent3].[ShipId] AS [ShipId2], [Extent3].[RankId] AS [RankId1], [Extent3].[ClearanceId] AS [ClearanceId1], [Extent3].[Description] AS [Description2], [Extent4].[RankId] AS [RankId2], [Extent4].[Description] AS [Description3], [Extent5].[ClearanceId] AS [ClearanceId2], [Extent5].[Description] AS [Description4]
            FROM   [dbo].[CrewMembers] AS [Extent3]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Ranks] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[RankId] = [Extent4].[RankId]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Clearances] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent3].[ClearanceId] = [Extent5].[ClearanceId] ) AS [Join2] ON [Extent2].[ShipId] = [Join2].[ShipId2] ) AS [Join3] ON [Extent1].[HarborId] = [Join3].[HarborId]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[HarborId] ASC, [Project1].[C2] ASC, [Project1].[ShipId] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

Comment: In the code where the issue arises, each class has a field `Description`. So, Harbor, Clearance, and Ship would need the description field as well.

Comment: @TravisJ: I'll do a quick test... one minute or two or three... :)

Comment: I do appreciate it :) I would rather be wrong than deal with having to manually create partial object graphs :P

Comment: @TravisJ: I have replaced test program code and screenshot by the new one. But it still looks correct to me.

Comment: I am unsure how to produce this in the format you provide here. Perhaps it is an artifact of the Dynamic Proxies which EF creates? Is the HashSet being cached here?

Comment: @TravisJ: If I disable proxies (`context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;` at the beginning of the 2nd `using` block) I get the same result. `HashSet` is not cached. The objects in the second `using` block are completely new because it's a new context. BTW: If you have SQL Express installed you can test this very easily: Create new console project in VS, add EF 4.3.1 via NuGet, copy code above into `program.cs`, run. EF creates a DB in your SQL Express with name `EFInclude.MyContext`.

Comment: I am unsure what leads to this not being easily reproduced in a local version. Perhaps when I have more time I will see if I can provide a contained example which exhibits this issue.

Comment: This issue requires more time to resolve. Although there is no definite resolution, I am going to award the bounty because this answer does describe a working example to this question in at least a localized format.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide the SQL statement?

Comment: @TravisJ: Yes, I have posted the SQL, see my Edit above. (And thanks for the bounty!)

Comment: What do you suppose would be the reason for the difference between our SQL statements? (Also note the strange `[Join2].[DESCRIPTION1] AS [DESCRIPTION11],` in mine).

Comment: @TravisJ: Most notably is that `[Join3].[Description]` is aliased four times (to `[Description1,2,3,4]`) in the 2nd SELECT block. It would mean that in the final `Project1` the value is the same for four of the descriptions. What version are your using exactly? EF 4.x or maybe EF 5.0? There are other small differences, like in your SQL the `CAST` isn't there in the `CASE` blocks, or no alias in the final SELECT.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, I somehow never noticed your comment. `<add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />`

Comment: `System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral`. Just updated hoping it would help but I am still getting the same results.

Comment: @TravisJ: I've added an Edit section on top of the answer refering to the new `MySql` tag. I could really have asked for the DB/provider your are using in the first place, I totally forgot how important this is :( It also explains why we had the different SQL we couldn't find the reason for.

Answer (score 8):

```
query.Include(entity => entity.Ships);
query.Include(entity => entity.Ships.Select(s => s.CrewMembers));
query.Include(entity => entity.Ships.Select(s => s.CrewMembers.Select(cm => cm.Rank)));
query.Include(entity => entity.Ships.Select(s => s.CrewMembers.Select(cm => cm.Clearance)));
```

First of all, you know it has to be `query = query.Include(...).Include(...)`, right?

As long as you are executing the last 2, you don't need the first 2. Both Ships and CrewMembers will be loaded from the second 2. Have you tried just this?

```
//query.Include(entity => entity.Ships);
//query.Include(entity => entity.Ships.Select(s => s.CrewMembers));
query = query.Include(entity => entity.Ships.Select(s => s.CrewMembers.Select(cm => cm.Rank)))
    .Include(entity => entity.Ships.Select(s => s.CrewMembers.Select(cm => cm.Clearance)));
```

Also, you can always fire up sql profiler to see exactly what query ef is sending to the db. I wouldn't expect a bug that would swap property values from different objects in the graph if you only run the 3rd and 4th Includes.

Comment: Just want to confirm -- you aren't using the `ObjectQueryExtensions.Include<T>(this ObjectQuery<T> query, Expression<Func<T, object>> selector)` method from the Thomas Levesque article are you? I assumed the `Include` method you were using is the `System.Data.Entity.DbExtensions.Include<T, TProperty>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> path)` method...

Comment: To be clear though, commenting out two lines of the .Include statement does not change anything.

Comment: When using `mySql Connector / NET` this approach causes a malformed `join`.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, it is not possible to retrieve the graph in one trip with EF when using the MySQLConnector/NET.  See this [confirmed bug report with Orcale](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67183). What must be done is to

```
DbSet<Harbor> dbSet = context.Set<Harbor>();
IQueryable<Harbor> query = dbSet;
query = query.Include(entity => entity.Ships.Select(s => s.CrewMembers));
var Harbor = query.ToList();
foreach (var S in Harbor.Ships)
{
 foreach (var CM in S.CrewMembers)
 {
  CM.Rank = //get Rank where RankId == CM.RankId
  CM.Clearance = //get Clearance where ClearanceId == CM.ClearanceId
 }
}
```

This code is in line with the example, but is obviously just as an example and would need better implementation to actually run. This is the approach I am using until I can overload or improve on the `.Include` EF functionality in order to get the whole graph in one trip.

Getting the data in multiple trips is not ideal, however, it works.