# Entity framework returning incorrect data from columns with same name

Tags: entity-framework, mysql-connector

I have a few tables in my database which are mapped to an edmx.  Using the entity framework to return data from these tables, I've encountered a problem where the value in the "name" column from one of my higher level data models is being populated into each model below it.

I'm pulling the data like this:

```
var query = (from a in context.things
             where a.id == 1
             select a);

var model = query.Select(a => new modelA()
{
    Name = a.name,
    Bs = a.Bs.Select(b => new modelB()
    {
        Name = b.name,
        Cs = b.Cs.Select(c => new modelC()
        {
            Name = c.name,
            Ds = c.Ds.Select(d => new modelD()
            {
                Name = d.name
            })
        })
    })
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

b.name, c.name and d.name are all returning the same value as a.name despite my database definitely having different values in across these tables.

Could this be a caching issue?

---

**Update**

After upgrading the mySql connector to the latest version (6.7.4.0) I am still encountering the error.

After the upgrade it seems i can get 3 levels deep before the data in the name column starts reappearing :(

Comment: What happens if you `Include()` the collections in the first query? I've seen all kinds of issues with EF + MySql, wouldn't be surprised to see yet another one.

Comment: drilling down through `context.things.Include(a => a.Bs.Select(b => b.Cs.Select(c => c.Ds)))` in debug mode show the wrong values for the name properties :(

Comment: A bug report for the `Include` problem with MySQL (which looks very similar to your `Select` problem) is here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67183 At the top two links to Stack Overflow with more detailed descriptions. In the very last reply at the bottom Oracle support says that the problem has been fixed in newer versions of the MySQL connector. Maybe check the version numbers from there and try to update if you use an older version currently.

Comment: @Elliott - Slauma helped a lot with this issue previously. I was the one who posted the bug report. Which version of the connector were you using? Also, if you want to ask me anything about this connector topic I am available in the c# chat room.

Comment: Cheers for the help guys.  Am currently in the process of updating the mySql connector so will let you know how it goes!

Comment: @Elliott - Can't wait :) If it doesn't work, I will post one of the workarounds I came across.

Comment: @TravisJ - still no luck! :( would you mind posting your workaround?

Comment: 2 year later, same situation, oracle is disappointing.
The workarounds is:extract nested key , do a pile separate query, and write back to wrong value fields to correct.